# Beside game assets, does polycount matter?

Tags: topology, polycount

I'm relatively new to Blender and there is one question that is sticking to my mind since I first discovered it could be an issue: Polycount.

I know that it is very important when building game assets for the sake of performance, but what about static renders? Should I always keep as low as possible or, since I'm just doing a static render, it doesn't really matter at all?

For example, I made this model a few months ago. To increase my skills on building the most variate objects, I decided to model everything in this scene. And by everything I mean everything, from the bolts in the body to the cable in the tow and gauges in the dashboard. The final file is 65mb with 5.257.780 tris. Is this okay?

[image]

Comment: I guess it counts for at least object maniability and render time. Also, if you animate, it will be much easier to rig and animate a low-poly.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: whatever you do, try to always keep a low-poly version, if you want a smooth surface, just use Smooth Shading and Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: If you render in Eevee, the polycount of a scene also influences render time. That's (one reason) why adaptive subdivision is such an exciting feature. Also, there is absolutely no benefit in having an asset with a million polygons, when it takes up only a small part of your render space. Oh, and great model, btw!

Comment: @JachymMichal - facecount *does* in fact affect render times. As I said, that's why adaptive subdivision is such a big deal. I had a scene (lots of rocks and stone blocks), where it reduced render times about 40%. Also explained [here](https://youtu.be/dRzzaRvVDng?t=87)

Comment: @metaphor_set Hi :). Good to know, I now realize I almost never use adaptive subdiv...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for all the inputs, references and the nice words! :D It is great to understand this concept better.